# How to change global variable in Jenkins mix pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a script like this [ code below ]
At the end of the stage block under node I get the desired result, but inside pipeline block I am not getting the changed value, instead it is giving me null. I tried all possible ways. Please let me know is there a way to get the changed value inside pipeline block.

```
def AGENT_LABEL
node('k8s-agent-large-mem-oci') {
  stage('Checkout and set agent'){
        sh '''
        if  [ ! -z "`echo ${ADE_LABEL} | grep  "BRONZE"`" ]
        then
            AGENT_LABEL="DB_OCI"
        fi
        if [ ! -z "`echo ${ADE_LABEL} | grep  "SILVER"`" ]
        then        
            AGENT_LABEL="DB_OCI"
        fi
        if [ ! -z "`echo ${ADE_LABEL} | grep  "FUSIONAPPS_11.13"`" ]
        then 
            AGENT_LABEL="DB_ARU"
        fi
        echo "Final Agent Label is $AGENT_LABEL"
        '''
    }
    
}
pipeline {
    agent {
       label "${AGENT_LABEL}"
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Git Copy to DB VM') {
            steps {
            echo "Running in ${AGENT_LABEL}"
            build job: 'Git_Scripts_DB'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before giving you a pipeline example, where do you set ${ADE_LABEL}?

Try this one:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  environment {
    AGENT_LABEL = """${sh(
      returnStdout: true,
      script: 'if [[ ! -z $(grep -E "BRONZE|SILVER" <<< "${ADE_LABEL}") ]]
                 then
                   AGENT_LABEL="DB_OCI"
               fi
               if [[ ! -z $(grep -E "FUSIONAPPS_11.13" <<< "${ADE_LABEL}") ]]
                 then
                   AGENT_LABEL="DB_ARU"
               fi
               echo "Final Agent Label is ${AGENT_LABEL}"'
    ).trim()}"""
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Git Copy to DB VM') {
      agent {
        label "${AGENT_LABEL}"
      }
      steps {
        echo "Running in ${AGENT_LABEL}"
        build job: 'Git_Scripts_DB'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just made 2 small changes :
1. agent {label ''}, gave an agent name right after pipeline.
2. echo "${AGENT_LABEL}"', so that it just get the value only, no other text.